# Cant get discord.py bot to disconnect from voice chat

Tags: discord.py

I have gotten the connect to work fine, but when trying to get the bot to disconnect, it will print that it has disconnected and will just sit their in chat with no errors. Here's the code:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def join(ctx):
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    await channel.connect()
    print('connected')

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def disconnect(ctx):
    server = ctx.message.guild.voice_client
    await server.disconnect()
    print ('disconnected')
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try using `server.disconnect(force=True)` ([documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.VoiceClient.disconnect)) as sometimes disconnecting may be blocked if you don't force it.

Comment: thanks for the response, it does disconnect the bot from the chat. However, now crashes the bot after using the command. Any advice?

Comment: Sadly not, I wish you the best of luck trying to deal with Discord voice. Potentially you can look into the basic voice example in the official repository: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/basic_voice.py