# Discord.py 2.0.0 voice chat disconnection problem

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
@commands.command(name="disconnect")
    async def _disconnect(self, ctx):
        voice_state = ctx.author.voice
        if voice_state is None:
            return
        for voice_client in ctx.bot.voice_clients:
            if voice_client.channel == ctx.author.voice.channel:
                await voice_client.disconnect()
                print("disconnected")
```

The code executes fine but the bot is still in voice chat

I tried changing `ctx.bot.voice_clients:` to `self.bot.voice_clients:` but it had no effect. I changed vesrion of discord.py multiple times but im still stuck on this

Comment: If you're using `self` that means it's probably in a class and we need to see more code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try `await voice_client.disconnect(force=True)`

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.VoiceClient.disconnect

[Cant get discord.py bot to disconnect from voice chat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61362031/cant-get-discord-py-bot-to-disconnect-from-voice-chat)